# Уязвим ли php код

Tags: php, уязвимости

```
<?php
$photo = $_REQUEST['photo'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "photos/".$photo .".gif");
?>
```

Уязвим ли данный код? Смогут ли обрезать .gif в названии файла и залить веб-шелл? Или можно не беспокоится? Кавычки код пишет в название файла почему-то, хотя фильтра нет.

Comment: нужно проверять mime тип и если это не картинка, выплевывать ошибку

Comment: Но данный код безопасен? Смогут ли загрузить .php файл?

Comment: После загрузки файла на сервер, до его переименования и перемещения в целевую папку - проверьте значение его MIME-типа, на перечень допустимых для вашей задачи. Но проверяйте тип не из значений массива $_FILES - их можно подделать, т.к. они приходят в запросе от клиента, а функцией ```mime_content_type()```

Comment: Это я понял, но даже если загрузить файл .php он будет в формате .gif и не получится запустить вредоносный код. Так выходит?

Comment: @Jigius Откуда такая вера в mime_content_type()? Вам никогда не приходило в голову, что файл может быть, к примеру, двух "типов" одновременно?

Comment: @Jack,  я вот предлагаю проверить и удалить, если проверку на тип не прошел ```
<?php
    $photo = $_REQUEST['photo'];
    $uploadedFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $mimeTypesArePermited = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'];
    if (in_array(mime_content_type($uploadedFile), $mimeTypesArePermited)) {
        move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile, "photos/".$photo .".gif");
    } else {
        // mime-type запрещен к загрузке
        unlink($uploadedFile);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Вы просто скажите уязвим ли код? Ну загрузят file.php грубо говоря и что? На сервере он будет находится file.php.gif.

Comment: @Jack, загрузят ```file.php```, его mime-type будет text/plain и не должен обрабатываться вашим скриптом как изображение. Нужно настроить конфигурацию сервера так, что если у вас папка с изображениями, то весь его контент рассматривается как статический и не обрабатывается php SAPI. Вообщем нюансов много, я согласен с @Ипатьев

Comment: Так всё-равно файл не запустится как php никак

Answer (score 0):

Старый дбрый веб-сервер апач по умолчанию настраивается так, чтобы исполнять файлы вида file.php.gif, как php.

Для надежности проще всего будет файл переименовывать.

Comment: Где настраивается? Я на apache загружаю и веб-браузер запускает файл, как .gif. И почему нельзя кавычками закрыть тут в $photo? Фильтров то нет, но кавычки пишет в название файла.

Comment: Что значит "запускает как .gif"? и при чем здесь кавычки вообще?

Comment: На apache если в конце файла gif, то браузер его и запускает как gif, а не как php.

Comment: осталось выяснить, при чем здесь браузер, если мы говорим о сервере

Comment: Для того, чтобы .gif обработался как php нужно создать .htaccess, а так браузер его выводит как изображение.

Answer (score 0):

Да, уязвим.

Если в `$photo` окажется что-то типа `../../../../usr/bin/aaa`, то это потенциально опасно.
Ну и в любом случае таким образом можно перезаписать любой gif-файл твоего сайта.

Имеет смысл сделать проверку на текст в `$photo` и почистить его до имени файла без пути и расширения. Впрочем, с расширением есть нюанс. Мне кажется, что имеет смысл оставлять оригинальное расширение, если оно находится в списке разрешённых.

И ещё: если разрешён svg, то стоит обратить внимание на возможность наличия в нём связей с внешними ресурсами.